# porque listview base adapter getItemId no admite ids de tipo string?

Tags: android-studio, listview, customadapter

Tengo un listview personalizado que se carga con los datos obtenidos de una base de datos. Para ello estoy utilizando `BaseAdapter` con lo cual me obliga a anular el metodo:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return listaObjetos.get(position).getId();
}
```

por desgracia este metodo solo devuelve el id del item en tipo `long` y yo necesito que cada item que se carga al listview almacene un id de tipo `String`, el corrector de android me sugiere que convierta el long en String quedando asi:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return Long.parseLong(listaObjetos.get(position).getId());
}
```

pero al hacer correr la aplicacion este se detiene ya que los ids que almaceno en mi base de datos contienen combinaciones de numeros y letras, y esta conversion de long a string no se puede realizar ya que no puede convertir las letras en tipo long. Como puedo solucionar este problema? o existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo?, necesito que en cada item pueda agregar y obtener (get, set) ids de tipo string.

ItemListViewCuentas.java:

```
public class ItemListViewCuentas {

//region Variables

private String id;
private int radioButton;
private byte[] fotoPerfil;
private String nombreCompleto;
private String correoElectronico;
private String numeroCelular;

//endregion

//region Constructor

public ItemListViewCuentas(String id, int radioButton, byte[] fotoPerfil, String nombreCompleto, String correoElectronico, String numeroCelular) {
    this.id = id;
    this.radioButton = radioButton;
    this.fotoPerfil = fotoPerfil;
    this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
    this.correoElectronico = correoElectronico;
    this.numeroCelular = numeroCelular;
}

//endregion

//region Getters and Setters


public String getId() { return id; }

public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

public int getRadioButton() { return radioButton; }

public void setRadioButton(int radioButton) { this.radioButton = radioButton; }

public byte[] getFotoPerfil() { return fotoPerfil; }

public void setFotoPerfil(byte[] fotoPerfil) { this.fotoPerfil = fotoPerfil; }

public String getNombreCompleto() { return nombreCompleto; }

public void setNombreCompleto(String nombreCompleto) { this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto; }

public String getCorreoElectronico() { return correoElectronico; }

public void setCorreoElectronico(String correoElectronico) { this.correoElectronico = correoElectronico; }

public String getNumeroCelular() { return numeroCelular; }

public void setNumeroCelular(String numeroCelular) { this.numeroCelular = numeroCelular; }

//endregion
}
```

ItemListViewAdapterCuentas.java

```
public class ItemListViewAdapterCuentas extends BaseAdapter {

//region Variables

private Context context;
private List<ItemListViewCuentas> listaObjetos;
private int selectedPosition;

//endregion

//region Constructor

public ItemListViewAdapterCuentas(Context context, List<ItemListViewCuentas> listaObjetos, int selectedPosition) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listaObjetos = listaObjetos;
    this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;
}

//endregion

//region Metodos

public void updateSelectedPosition(int selectedPosition){
    this.selectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() { return listaObjetos.size(); }

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) { return listaObjetos.get(position); }

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return Long.parseLong(listaObjetos.get(position).getId());
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View viewListAccount;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        viewListAccount = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget_item_cuentas_busqueda_avanzada, null);
    }else{
        viewListAccount = convertView;
    }

    ImageView imageViewRadioButton = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.imgView_RadioButton);
    ImageView imageViewFotoPerfil = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.imgView_FotoPerfil);
    TextView textViewNombre = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.txtView_Nombre);
    TextView textViewCorreoElectronico = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.txtView_CorreoElectronico);
    TextView textViewNumeroCelular = viewListAccount.findViewById(R.id.txtView_Numero_Celular);

    imageViewRadioButton.setImageResource(listaObjetos.get(position).getRadioButton());
    Glide.with(context).load(listaObjetos.get(position).getFotoPerfil()).into(imageViewFotoPerfil);
    textViewNombre.setText(listaObjetos.get(position).getNombreCompleto());
    textViewCorreoElectronico.setText(listaObjetos.get(position).getCorreoElectronico());
    textViewNumeroCelular.setText(listaObjetos.get(position).getNumeroCelular());

    if(selectedPosition == position){
        imageViewRadioButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_checked_tea500_20dp);
    }else{
        imageViewRadioButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio_button_unchecked_tea500_20dp);
    }

    return viewListAccount;
}

//endregion
}
```

Comment: Hola. Es que la función getItemId solo puede retornar un long. Pero visto para lo que la necesitas en tu ejemplo, puedes prescindir totalmente de ella, y limitarte a retornar el position que recibes como parametro. Con ese cambio ya te debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que es un malentendido, **en tu `Adapter` únicamente necesitas definir el método `getItemId()` pero lo que debes retornar es la posición del elemento**:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    //return Long.parseLong(listaObjetos.get(position).getId());
    return position;
}
```

Recuerda el proposito del método

> **[getItemId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int))** Obtiene el id de la fila asociada con la posición
>   especificada en la lista.